# MarkLogic 8 object to document-node

Tags: marklogic

This is a problem I have encountered many times before. I can't get a grip on types when loading data into MarkLogic.

The function source.createSource expects:

```
  $title as xs:string,
  $dataset as xs:string?,
  $content as document-node()*
```

The typeof(input) shows it's an object. So I need to go from this object to a document node.

**Data**

```
{   "id": "123",
    "something": "yes"
}
```

**Error**

> 2015-08-19 09:26:35.150 Info: vriend: Status 500: JS-JAVASCRIPT: sourceId = source.createSource(title, dataset, source); -- Error running JavaScript request: TypeError: undefined is not a function

**Script**

```
/**
 * @name vriendingest 
 * This REST extension provides SOAP service for the shipment data
 */

//declareUpdate();

var eput   = require("/MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/endpoint-util.xqy");
var link   = require("/ext/obi/lib/link-lib.xqy");
var object = require("/ext/obi/lib/object-service-lib.xqy", "/ext/obi/lib/object-lib.xqy");
var source = require("/ext/obi/lib/source-lib.xqy");

function put(context, params, input) {
   xdmp.log('input ' + typeof(input));

   var data = input.toObject();

   xdmp.log('data ' + typeof(data));
   xdmp.log(data.length);

   testing  = source.buildUri('takethisuri');
   title    = 'test';
   source   = data;
   dataset  = "cswifi";

   sourceId = source.createSource(title, dataset, source);

   xdmp.log(sourceId);

   response = '{success: "or something"}';
   context.outputTypes = ["application/xml"];
   context.outputStatus = [200, "OK"];

   return response;
}

// Main
exports.PUT = put;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is hiding your earlier definition of `source`:

```
source   = data;
```

I recommend putting `var` in front of variables that should be local to a function. Validating your code with JSHint with such extra vars, and with `'use strict';` inside the function tells me `source` is being redefined. I don't think you want to hide the require for source-lib with the value of data..

HTH!

Comment: Changed it, still the same problem. thanks for the editor tip but I've never found any editor supporting MarkLogic REST extensions. I use the MarkLogic Sublime plugin but it doesn't support SJS as it seems.

Comment: Finally noticed that the 'declare namespace' conversion interfered with the var in the function. Thanks again.